# Laravel Passport Password Reset API route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm all set up with Passport in 5.5 and have the auto generated `Auth\ForgotPasswordController` and `Auth\ResetPasswordController` controllers.

However whereas /oauth/token was provided magically for me, there don't appear to be such routes for password reset when using the API.

What should my API routes look like?

Currently I've experimented with

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'password'], function () {
    Route::post('/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

but I found these in the vendor files when looking at the traits and aren't sure if this is the correct way.

The `/password/email` route also fails with `"message": "Route [password.reset] not defined."`

Comment: Have you done `php artisan route:list` to see if the route is listed? It could have the prefix `/api` before `/password/email`

Comment: Only my 2 custom ones are listed. I remove the /api/ as my subdomain is api.domain.com, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Did you add Auth::routes() to the api routes and or web?

Comment: I didn't add any of the passport auth routes to either, the /oauth/ paths seem to work magically. They aren't present in either api.php or web.php. I'm now assuming that passport provides me with ways to login but not reset passwords

Comment: You have 2 options either register a route called `password.reset` in you either web or api route file or just run `php artisan make:auth` laravel will bootstrap all the routes for you with login/signup. As @rchatburn mention dont forget to register Auth::routes() in web.php route

Answer (score 1):

since you don't see any route other then 2 custom, therefore  i am assumin you havn't run `artisan auth` command. First run that. it will add lot of routes in ur project.
Then set api driver to passport.

Comment: I have already ran artisan auth command. And I have all the routes listed. Now I want api for reset password and registration. I have api for login as http://localhost:8080/oauth/token