# Laravel Passport Password Reset API roue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm struggling to get this done.

I have executed `php artisan make: auth` and the web-pages work perfectly, but now I want to use this using the API.

If I just try localhost/password/reset I get an HTML-page with the text: "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.".

If I add the header `Accept: application/json` I get a HttpException and it's not clear to me why I get that exception

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930940/laravel-passport-password-reset-api-route) but it doesn't help me

I want to keep using Passport and not JWTAuth

Comment: One thing you should know that Laravel 5.3 Passport using JWT Authentication.

Comment: Okay. Didnt't know that. Is [this](https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt) maybe helpful for me?

Comment: To use with apis you need to implement passport package.

Comment: @SebastiaanSpeck Did you got anything with respect to this? I am also facing the same issue.